# Why is onclick not able to find my function

Tags: javascript

I have a form and inside it there is a button.

```
<form>
  <button type="button" onclick="hello(); return false;">Hi</button>
</form>
```

I'm trying to call `hello` which is in my javascript file but I'm getting the error:

```
(index):43 Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):43)
```

I'm using [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/09bp5cga/). My JavaScript is located in the JavaScript panel.

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it (in JavaScript)?

Comment: Well, where do you define your hello function? A [mcve] would be nice

Comment: Where is the definition of `hello()` ?

Comment: @j08691 I'm using JSFiddle. My JavaScript is located in the JavaScript panel.

Comment: Add a link to it then @templateboy

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/09bp5cga/

Comment: jsFiddle by default loads your JS into a window.onload handler. That aside, you should always post a [mcve] here. See the difference when you pick the right option: https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/47q91zuv/?

Comment: @j08691 What exactly did you do?

Comment: In your fiddle I clicked the JS dropdown menu and changed the load type from on load to no wrap/head.

Answer (score -1):

Place your javascript function inside body tag, it resolves the issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <button type="button" onclick="hello(); return false;">
  Hi
  </button>
</form>

<script>
function hello() {
    alert("Hello");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```